# Need clarity related to prayers,taharah

Tags: salat, taharah, ghusl

I am a virgin woman,I never had any se**ual intercourse ever,I don't know how orgasm feels like,but I feel like tingling and weird sensation+ discharge.sometimes for a whole day,time to time,how should I pray ,is my ghusl valid,and when I check my discharge color is Yellow,white ,brown,I try my best to avoid it these sensations feels at any time.